# Bootstrap horizontal navbar plus sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sidebar

[image]I'm trying to create an application layout utilizing the Bootstrap framework that has both a horizontal navbar as well as a vertical sidebar.

The basic layout I have is:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            Logo
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <ul class="nav" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            </nav>
            <br />
            <h2>Body</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, what I'd like is for the navbar to be positioned beginning at column 3. Currently it is positioned to the left, effectively covering the logo.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. I'd like the solution to be responsive.

Regards,

Dan

Comment: Do you want the sidebar below the navbar/logo?

Comment: The logo is at the very top of the sidebar.  I need the sidebar to extend all the way to the top. However because of design considerations, I can't incorporate the logo in the navbar (color conflicts).